# Send date values to controller from cshtml page

Tags: razor, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using .NetCore and Entity Framework to design a site.

On the site, I have a cshtml page that displays a table of data like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CharacterId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CharacterDisplayName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimePathYear)
            </td>

            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.CharacterId">Edit</a> |
            </td>
        </tr>
}
```

Where, when the user clicks on the "Edit" link, it will send them to this controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id) { }
```

However, I now want to pass in a user-selectable date range so that the controller would look like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id, DateTime? start, DateTime? end) { }
```

So I added these two date controls to the cshtml page:

```
    <div class="datePickers">
        <div class="startDate">
            Start Date
            <input id="inputStartDate" type="date" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="endDate">
            End Date
            <input id="inputEndDate" type="date" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"/>
            <button formaction="/Characters/Index/">Go</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But how would I add the date values they select to the asp-action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you put the startDate and startDate , i assume you put the two date select input on top of your table :

```
    <div class="datePickers">
    <div class="startDate">
        Start Date
        <input id="inputStartDate" type="date" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="endDate">
        End Date
        <input id="inputEndDate" type="date" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"/>
        <button formaction="/Characters/Index/">Go</button>
    </div>
</div>


@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CharacterId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CharacterDisplayName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimePathYear)
        </td>

        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.CharacterId">Edit</a> |
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Then you can use Jquery to dynamically append the query string by :

```
@section Scripts{

<script>

    $(function () {
        $('#inputStartDate').on('change', function () {
            var querystring = 'inputStartDate=' + $("#inputStartDate").val() + '&inputEndDate=' + $("#inputEndDate").val();
            $("a").each(function () {

                var href = $(this).attr('href').split('?')[0];

                if (href) {
                    href += (href.match(/\?/) ? '&' : '?') + querystring;
                    $(this).attr('href', href);

                }
            });
        });
    })
```

And when user click the edit link , you could get parameters from server side :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id, DateTime? inputStartDate, DateTime? inputEndDate)
{

}
```